# Can I lift 15 tons on air bearings with 0.2 kg air/s?

Tags: airflow, bearings, air

The air is at 13 kPa and 400 K. I can raise both the supply temperature and the pressure if necessary. No problem with that. I could get 1.7 kg/s for the air bearings, but I have no more air.

I thought levitation this way was possible, but I'm doubtful now because there's an Australian engineer who's skeptical.

Elon Musk said it was possible, but Hyperloop critics deny it.

Comment: Elon had the vision not the proof.  Noone does yet. https://www.engadget.com/2018/04/12/hyperloop-tt-begins-construction-of-its-first-test-track/

Comment: Thank you. I'll stick with the air bearings formulae I know and I'll see what the results hold. I don't have CFD simulation software, but I'll do what I can.

Comment: There's no magic involved, despite what Musk seems to believe. Hovercraft have been a thing for decades and can lift a lot more than 15 tons. Learn from that experience, not "hyped" and/or "loop(y)" concepts ;) .